# Perturbation method when the differential equation depends on $\epsilon^2$ only

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I have a differential equation of the form
$$
y'' + p(x) y' + (1-\epsilon^2 q(x)) y = 0\ ,
$$
where $y$ is also a function of $x$.

I'm supposed to apply a perturbation method via a regular expansion
$$
y = y_0 + \epsilon y_1 + \epsilon^2 y_2 + \dots
$$
such that I don't need to know $p(x)$ in order to calculate the dominant term $y_0$. I don't see how is that possible, since I would end up with an equation like
$$
y_0'' + p(x) y_0' + y_0 = 0
$$

I have never seen an equation where the small parameter appears as $\epsilon^2$ instead of $\epsilon$, so I don't know if that is the key for solving this the correct way. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just redefine $\delta := \epsilon^2$ and apply the machinery?

Comment: @DanDoe I thought about it but, wouldn't that still give a differential equation for $y_0$ dependent on $p(x)$?

Comment: @Jaime_mc2 what do you know of $q(x)$, what can you assume on $q(x)$?